# Using for loops and x += 1 --- SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax-error

I'm trying to run a for loop within a string, and I get that error.

Here's my code and the error I get:

code:

```
from cmath import inf
from tkinter import Y
from typing import Counter

def function(x, y):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    s = "LRLRLRGLRGRLGRRRGRGLRG"
    n = range(-100,100)
    n_R = s.count("R", 0, 10)
    n_L = s.count("L", 0, 10)
    print(n_R)
    print(n_L)

    for c in s:
        if n_R - n_L == 4 + 4*n:
            return y += 1

        elif n_R - n_L == 3 + 4*n:
            return x -= 1

        elif n_R - n_L == 2 + 4*n:
            return y -= 1

        else n_R - n_L == 1 + 4*n:
            return x += 1

    return x
    return y
```

Error:

```
return y += 1
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried `y = y + 1`, and I get the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Its a syntax error. What do you want it to mean?

Comment: What is `return y += 1` supposed to do? How about `return y+1`?

Comment: `y += 1` is a *statement*, not an *expression* - it has no value as would be needed to use it in a `return` statement.  You'd need to separately do the `return y` - or simply do `return y + 1` (there's no point in modifying `y`, as it ceases to exist when the function returns).

Comment: You cannot have assignment/augmented assignment as part of return statement

Comment: Also note that last `return y` will never be reached, because `return x` will end the function in case all the previous returns did not

Comment: @D.L what other errors do you see? I fixed the one I asked for help, but I'm having another invalid sintax with this part: "n_R - n_L == 4 + 4*n"

Comment: That's a new question. If we've solved your immediate problem this is the end of this question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of errors in the code, but focusing on the error specifically referred to, this would resolve:

```py
    for c in s:
        if n_R - n_L == 4 + 4*n:
            y += 1
            return y
```

The reason why this is the case is because `y += 1` is actually a statement. Whereas, the OP needs to increment `y` before it is returned as a value.

Comment: Surely this is simplified to `return 1`?

Comment: @quamrana,   that would only be the case if `y=1`.

Comment: But it looks like the intention is that `y` starts at 0, then inside this `if` it becomes 1 and gets returned.

Comment: @quamrana.  i would actually point out that this is a **semantic error** in the first instance given that both `x` and `y` are inputs into the function which are immediately overwritten with zero !  Nevertheless, `y +=1` in the `return` is a **syntax error** on its own.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's what I say in the first comment. I'm just pointing out a simplifying step to your answer.